# Configure Outlook 2010 connection speed settings

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

In Outlook 2003 I was able to configure the connection speed below which the software would take a different action (I.e. might only download headers rather than full email).

How can I configure this in Outlook 2010? I have downloaded the group policy addin for Office 2010, but the connection speed is not part of that.

This is causing a problem because my laptop has a mobile broadband card in it, and that reports 1Mbps or so - regardless of the actual speed that is has connected - and when I am on a customer site, I don't really want to be downloading whole emails via mobile broadband (if an email arrived with a 20 MB attachment it would use up a fair chunk of my mobile broadband allowance!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer...

Outlook 2010 Admin templates..MS Outlook 2010 => Account Settings => Exchange =>cached Exchange low bandwidth threshold - 2010